# threading.Thread not executing loops on functions

Tags: jupyter-notebook, python-3.6

I've been trying to code an auto-clicker, but I first needed to learn how to use the Thread library, but I don't know why the code just stop when it runs the first time at the loop.

```
import time 

from threading import Thread 

def countdown(n):
    while n > 0:
        print('T-minus', n) 
        n -= 1
        time.sleep(5) 

t = Thread(target = countdown, args =(10, )) 
t.start()
```

The output is only:

```
>>> T-minus 10
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just understood what was going on! If you trying to run a thread on a Jupyter Cell, it won't show the output, I changed the code a bit to test it.

```
import time 

from threading import Thread 

TIMES = 0

def countdown(n):
    global TIMES
    while n > 0:
        TIMES += 1
        time.sleep(5)

t = Thread(target = countdown, args =(10, )) 
t.start()
```

And in the next cell I just kept printing the TIMES value and it was changing! but just in the background!

```
for i in range(10):
    time.sleep(3)
    print(TIMES)
```